# How can I redirect a url with ? in it

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect

https://www.example.com/?uid=XXX
to https://www.example.com/uid/XXX

I searched it quite a bit, the closet thing I found is [this url](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/) but even that does not show how it can be done. The problem is if url has ? in it, it cannot be redirected with catching text from query string. This is what I have tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uid=(.*)$

RewriteRule (.*) /uid/$1
```

[test bed](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=b2bc98e9-25c1-59f4-bafe-56ab1fc4de0b)

Comment: Why -1 vote? Any reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back references to the last RewriteCond use the form `%x`, not `$x`.

You don’t need a RewriteCond to check if this is the root URL, you can do that in the Rule, by checking for an empty path.

If you want to redirect, you will have to add the `R` flag for that.

And to prevent the original query string from being appended again, a trailing question mark at the end of the substitution URL can be used.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uid=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /uid/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you didn't know that!